# How to do information extraction from a fragmented text in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, nltk, spacy

I am reading a large text file in Python, which looks like the following (contains many `Code` and `Description` information).

```
Over-ride Flag for Site/Laterality/Morphology (Interfield Edit 42)

This field is used to identify whether a case was reviewed and coding confirmed 
for paired-organ primary
site cases with an in situ behavior and the laterality is not coded right, 
left, or one side involved, right or left
origin not specified.

Code           Description

Blank          Not reviewed, or reviewed and corrected

1                  Reviewed and confirmed as reported: A patient had behavior 
code of in situ and laterality is not
stated as right: origin of primary; left: origin of primary; or only one side 
involved, right or left
origin not specified

This field is used to identify whether a case was reviewed and coding confirmed 
for cases with a non-
specific laterality code.

Code           Description

Blank1          Not reviewed

11                   A patient had laterality 
coded non-specifically and
extension coded specifically

This field, new for 2018, indicates whether a case was reviewed and coding    
............
```

From the above free text I need to store only code and description values into two lists like following.

```
code = ["Blank", "1", "Blank1", "11"]
des = ["Not reviewed, or reviewed and corrected", "Reviewed and confirmed as reported: A patient had behavior code of in situ and laterality is not stated as right: origin of primary; left: origin of primary; or only one side involved, right or left origin not specified", "Not reviewed", "A patient had laterality coded non-specifically and extension coded specifically"]
```

How can I do it in Python?

Note: The `Code` can contain a "Blank (or Blank1)" keyword or a numeric value. Sometimes code `Description` is fragmented in multiple lines. In the above example, I am showing that one `Code` and `Description` block contains two codes and two descriptions. However, one `Code` and `Description` block can contain one or more than one codes and descriptions.

Answer (score 3):

We can solve this with an algorithm/state machine. The following code opens your file called "datafile.txt" in the same directory as the python script, parses it, and prints the results. The keys to the algorithm are assuming that there are empty lines *only* between every two fields and that any line containing the beginning of a description field we want to record has its code attribute separated from its description attribute by three or more spaces. These assumptions are always going to be true as far as I can tell from your file snippet.

```
index = -1
record = False
description_block = False
codes = []
descriptions = []
with open("datafile.txt", "r") as file:
  for line in file:
    line = [portion.strip() for portion in line.split("   ") if portion != ""]
    if record:
      if len(line) == 2:
        index += 1
        codes.append(line[0])
        descriptions.append(line[1])
      else:
        if line[0]:
          description_block = True
        if description_block:
          if not line[0]:
            description_block = False
            record = False
            continue
          else:
            descriptions[index] += " "+line[0]
    if line[0] == "Code":
      record = True
print("codes:", codes)
print("descriptions:", descriptions)
```

Result:

```
codes: ['Blank', '1', 'Blank1', '11']
descriptions: ['Not reviewed, or reviewed and corrected', 'Reviewed and confirmed as reported: A patient had behavior code of in situ and laterality is not stated as right: origin of primary; left: origin of primary; or only one side involved, right or left origin not specified', 'Not reviewed', 'A patient had laterality coded non-specifically and extension coded specifically']
```

Tested in python 3.8.2

EDIT:
Updating the code to reflect the whole data file as provided in the comments.

```
import re
column_separator = "     "
index = -1
record = False
block_exit = False
break_on_newline = False
codes = []
descriptions = []
templine = ""
def add(line):
  global index
  index += 1
  block_exit = False
  codes.append(line[0])
  descriptions.append(line[1])
with open("test", "r", encoding="utf-8") as file:
  while True:
    line = file.readline()
    if not line:
      break
    if record:
      line = [portion.strip() for portion in line.split(column_separator) if portion != ""]
      if len(line) > 1:
        add(line)
      else:
        if block_exit:
            record = False
            block_exit = False
        else:
          if line[0]:
            descriptions[index] += " "+line[0]
          else:
            while True:
              line = [portion.strip() for portion in file.readline().split(column_separator) if portion != ""]
              if not line:
                break
              if len(line) > 1:
                if templine:
                  descriptions[index] += templine
                  templine = ""
                add(line)
                break
              else:
                print(line)
                if line[0] and "Instructions" not in line[0]:
                  templine += " "+line[0]
                else:
                  if break_on_newline:
                    break_on_newline = False
                    record = False
                    templine = ""
                    break
                  else:
                    templine += " "+line[0]
                    break_on_newline = True
    else:
      if line == "Code           Description\n":
        record = True

print("codes:", codes)
print("\n")
print("descriptions:", descriptions)

# for i in range(len(codes)):
#   print(codes[i]+"\t\t", descriptions[i])
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution. It works for some parts of the input file. However, the solution is not working for the whole input file. Could you please provide me a better solution. You can test with my input file. It is available here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1KLXoyhTq9jLzNrQTJFotRj2M750ImBG9/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Try the following regex approach:

```
blanks = re.findall(r'\bCode\b.*?\bDescription\s*?(\S+)\s+.*?\r?\n(\d+)\s+.*?(?=\r?\n\r?\n)', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
print(blanks)

reviews = re.findall(r'\bCode\b.*?\bDescription\s*?\S+\s+(.*?)\r?\n\d+\s+(.*?)(?=\r?\n\r?\n)', inp, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

This prints:

```
[('Blank', '1'), ('Blank1', '11')]

[('Not reviewed, or reviewed and corrected\n', 'Reviewed and confirmed as reported: A patient had behavior \ncode of in situ and laterality is not\nstated as right: origin of primary; left: origin of primary; or only one side \ninvolved, right or left\norigin not specified'), ('Not reviewed\n', 'A patient had laterality \ncoded non-specifically and\nextension coded specifically')]
```

The idea here is to just match and capture the various desired portions of the `Code ... Description ... Blank` portions of your input text.  Note that this answer assumes that you have already read the text into a Python string variable.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I am reading input from a big text file (one line at a time). How can I read a big text file in the Python string variable? Please let me know.

Comment: Then you might need to read block by block and then use regex to extract.

Comment: How to read block by block to use regex? Could you please provide me an example code? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Your `blanks` and `reviews` regex commands return only two code values or two description values. I have more than two codes and description values in some portion of the input file. Could you please let me know how to get more than two codes or descriptions?